Possible to extract scaled versions from Scalable Video Coding video?
Video can be encoded using Scalable Video Coding (SVC) with either temporal or spatial scalability. Assuming a video is available with SVC, is it possible to extract the different "versions" of the video using ffmpeg or another tool without having to transcode or process the raw video content?
